# Cannot download a file from MVC Controller talks to Web Api Download File

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have a Asp.Net WebApi and a Asp.Net MVC Web project. Web Api provides file download function. Browser requests the DownloadController in MVC WebClient which talks to Web Api File download controller.

I referred to [this](http://arcware.net/upload-and-download-files-with-web-api-and-azure-blob-storage/) article to implement file download to the WebApi.(I trid to call the web api directly from the browser as mentioned in the example and it worked). But in my case I need to send the file to the browser via the MVC Web App. 
I get the memory stream to the Webserver (MVC Controller), and in the WebServer temp folder (C:\Temp folder), it creates a file but the size is 0kb and It cannot be opened (Cannot read the file, some process is using it). When IIS is restarted, it gives the error "Format exception: Not a valid PDF or corrupted".

Browser gets a Download Pdf and it says Loading, but never completes.

I am keeping the Memory stream open until the file download completes in the Web Api. Otherwise I get a null response from Web Api to Web server.

Am I doing something which is not recommended? What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Here is the code,

Web Api project, Download file function

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetById(string fileid)
 {         
          //fileid = e.g. <someguid>.pdf
        try
        {                                
          var result = DownloadBlob(fileid);

          if (result == null)
          {
             return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
          }

         result.BlobStream.Position = 0;
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);

      }
   }
```

MVC Web App (talks to Web Api and needs to send file response)

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadInvoice()
        {
            string id = "6bc7fb58-4bd3-4a09-bd90-98a837d4e441.pdf";

            //Call WebApiClient
            BcxApiConfiguration config = new BcxApiConfiguration();//This will load settings. These settings will be used in HMAC
            BcxBillingApi<BcxInvoiceFile> invoiceApi = new BcxBillingApi<BcxInvoiceFile>(config.Uri, config.AppId, config.ApiKey, organisationId);

            BcxInvoiceFile result = await invoiceApi.GetByIdAsync(id);

            //WRITE TO FILE
            string path = @"C:\Temp\" + result.BlobFileName;
            var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            fileStream.Position = 0;
            fileStream.CopyTo(result.BlobStream);

            return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");

        }
```

Download Helper in Web Api,

```
public BcxInvoiceFile DownloadBlob(string blobFileId)
{
            var billingFileInstanceFileName = String.Empty;
            string destFile;
            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageAccountConnectionString);

            // Create the blob client.
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve Storage container.
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(StorageContainer);

            // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
            container.CreateIfNotExists();


            // Retrieve Blob Reference.
            var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobFileId);           

            string text;
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
            text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

            // Strip off any folder structure so the file name is just the file name
            var lastPos = blockBlob.Name.LastIndexOf('/');
            var fileName = blockBlob.Name.Substring(lastPos + 1, blockBlob.Name.Length - lastPos - 1);

            // Build and return the download model with the blob stream and its relevant info
            var download = new BcxInvoiceFile
            {
                BlobStream = memoryStream,
                BlobFileName = fileName,
                BlobLength = blockBlob.Properties.Length,
                BlobContentType = blockBlob.Properties.ContentType
            };

            return download;

            // return billingFileInstanceFileName;
 }
```

Model class for file download,

```
 public class BcxInvoiceFile
 {
        public MemoryStream BlobStream { get; set; }
        public string BlobFileName { get; set; }
        public string BlobContentType { get; set; }
        public long BlobLength { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: shouldn't this line `fileStream.CopyTo(result.BlobStream);` be 
`await fileStream.CopyToAsync(result.BlobStream);`

Comment: Tried that, no change. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did few experiments with streams and found a solution which keeps things simple.
Solution:

Simply pass the byte array from Web Api to MVC controller and then create a filestream from MVC controller.

From the Web Api Controller,

```
result.BlobStream.Position = 0;

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.BlobStream.GetBuffer());
```

From the MVC controller, (plain c# code without the Api client I am using)

```
 public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadInvoice()
        {
            string invoiceId = new Guid(); //Test data
            var url = "http://localhost:7000/api/v1/downloadfile/<invoiceid goes here>";

            string path = @"C:\Temp\" + invoiceId + ".pdf";

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Byte[]>();

                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, stream);

                var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

                return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
            }
        }
```

If anyone come across a better way, please let me know.